# how to display docx or pdf in browser using mvc5

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, pdf, docx

I am working on project in which I want to display docx or pdf in browser, these documents are coming from database as binary data. Here is my code

Controller

```
private DiagnosticDetailModel GetFileList(int id)
        {
            var DetList = db.DiagnosticDetailModels.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return DetList;

        }
 [HttpGet]
        public ActionResult RetrieveFile(int id)
        {

           DiagnosticDetailModel diagnosticDetailModel = GetFileList(id);

            byte[] img = diagnosticDetailModel.FileContent.ToArray();
            string s = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(img);
            Response.Buffer = true;
            Response.Cache.SetCacheability(HttpCacheability.NoCache);
            Response.BinaryWrite(img);

            Response.AppendHeader("Content-Disposition", "inline");
            ViewData["myInnerHtml"] = s;
               return View("test", ViewData["myInnerHtml"]);


        }
```

test.cshtml

```
<div id="doc-viewer-id" style="width:500px; height:500px;">
    @(new HtmlString(ViewData["myInnerHtml"].ToString()))


</div>
```

index.cshtml

```
<table>
    <thead style="background-color:#5bc0de; color:white;font-size:14px;">
        <tr>
            <th>#</th>
            <th>
                Diagnostic Name
            </th>
            <th>
                Registration Date
            </th>

            <th>View Report</th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody style="font-size:12px;">
        @foreach (var item in Model)
        {
            <tr>
                <td></td>

                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.DiagnosticName)
                </td>
                <td>
                    @Html.DisplayFor(modelItem => item.Date)
                </td>

                <td>

                    @Html.ActionLink("View", "RetrieveFile", new { id = item.Id }, new { @class = "btn btn-primary btn-sm fa fa-eye", @style = "color:white;background-color:#5bc0de;",@target="_blank" })

                </td>
            </tr>
        }
    </tbody>
</table>
```

when I click on button to display document in browser I am getting data like this which is showing in below image

[image]

anyone know where I am doing wrong in code?

Comment: Can you share the code of `GetFileList` method?

Comment: Looks like you are getting content and not the file and trying to render it. You should try to get the file path (verify the path by putting it in browser and file should download). If path is correct, set it as source of an IFRAME in your view.

Comment: PDF or Word files are not HTML, so they can't be just "embedded" in HTML as you're trying to do. If you want them embedded, you should either use an IFrame, or you will have to convert those documents first, to Images or to HTML.

Comment: `private DiagnosticDetailModel GetFileList(int id)
        {
            var DetList = db.DiagnosticDetailModels.Where(p => p.Id == id).FirstOrDefault();
            return DetList;

        }` 
@ChetanRanpariya

Comment: Please share the code in the question itself .

Comment: i have tried with iframe '<iframe src="@ViewData["myInnerHtml"]" style="width:600px; height:500px;" frameborder="0"></iframe>'
still getting same data

Comment: i did @ChetanRanpariya

Comment: i dont want to get file from path as these documents will upload by third party in database as binary format i just want to dispay them

Comment: i dont want to get file from path as these documents will upload by third party in database as binary format i just want to dispay them